Next.js - Call other backend with jwt token using server actions
I have the following problem, I am using Nextjs with NextAuth and I want to make calls to another backend. To do it I need to set the Bearer token in the Authorization header. I don't want to expose the token to the client, that's why I want to get it in server action. However, to get the token I need the function getToken({req}), and I don't have access to the req in my server actions.
I am open to other suggestions on how to fetch the data from other backends using server components.

You will first need to configure Auth options. refer to https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#callbacks. Here the idToken should be set in callbacks, jwt section.  Please note where you get your idToken might vary in your use case. For example,
 async jwt({ token, account }) {
  if (account?.id_token) {
    token.idToken = account.id_token
  }

  return token
},

In sever action / page / route, you can call getServerSesion to get the idToken. For example,
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
if (!session?.idToken) {
  throw new Error("No session found")
}


You can use API Routes for this instead of server actions.
Server Actions are an abstraction over API routes and are useful for CRUD operations where the necessary code only interfaces with components that are already part of your application, like a database or cache.
If you need to reach out to a 3rd party, you could use an API route, which you call from your frontend using an API request (ex: fetch). In your API route, you will have access to the req object which contains your authentication token in the header.
Another option, if you’re in a Server component, is to read the header of the request and then extract the token from there manually.
